# jqGrid pagination mixing first page data with second page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When the page is loaded for the first time,  I am displaying 50 records and  when I clicked on next page, I observed that some of the first page data is appearing on the second page. When I go back to first page, that data is missing.

Below are the configurations after `colNames` and `colModel` declarations

```
loadonce: true,
datatype : 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
width: '937',
height: 'auto',
rownumbers: false,
sortable :true,
sortname : 'lastUpdatedDt',
sortorder : 'desc',
scrollOffset : 0,
rowNum : jqrowNum,
rowList : jqRecordsPerPageList,
viewrecords : false,
gridview : false,
cellEdit : false,
caption : 'Search Results',
hidegrid : false,
pager : jQuery('#assetSearchResultsPager'),
multiselect : true,
toolbar: [true,"top,bottom"],
toppager: true,
jsonReader: { repeatitems : false, id: "0" },
```